# Is it possible to use Template Tags in Django 1.11 to get around a "NoneType" Error?

Tags: django-template-filters

I am using template tags to present data that has been derived from class objects on the back end. Both class objects require inputs from the user to work and if the input is not valid they return None.

I need to present a difference calculation of two of the objects on the page (it does not need to be saved to the database). So I have installed mathfilters https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mathfilters  to do the subtraction which worked if there is user input but does not work if I am just navigating to the page or no user input.

Template HTML:

```
<tr>
   <td>Interest</td>
   <td class="data">${{int_numbers.get_sum_int_daily_numbers  | intcomma }}</td>
   <td class="data">${{int_goals.get_div_goalsint_wdays | intcomma }}</td>
   <td class="data"><font class="red">
    ${{ int_numbers.get_sum_int_daily_numbers|sub:int_goals.get_div_goalsint_wdays | intcomma }}
                </font>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Which gives me this error:

```
Traceback:

File "C:\pycharm-virtenv\DjangoPostgres\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  882.                     current = current[bit]

During handling of the above exception ('NoneType' object is not subscriptable), another exception occurred:

File "C:\pycharm-virtenv\DjangoPostgres\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  890.                         current = getattr(current, bit)

During handling of the above exception ('NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_div_goalsint_wdays'), another exception occurred:

File "C:\pycharm-virtenv\DjangoPostgres\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  896.                             current = current[int(bit)]

During handling of the above exception (invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'get_div_goalsint_wdays'), another exception occurred:

File "C:\pycharm-virtenv\DjangoPostgres\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\pycharm-virtenv\DjangoPostgres\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\pycharm-virtenv\DjangoPostgres\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\DevProj\am\amreports\reports\views.py" in goals_view
  61.         'int_monthtodate': int_monthtodate_goals,

File "C:\pycharm-virtenv\DjangoPostgres\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
  30.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "C:\pycharm-virtenv\DjangoPostgres\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  68.     return template.render(context, request)

File "C:\pycharm-virtenv\DjangoPostgres\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\pycharm-virtenv\DjangoPostgres\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  207.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\pycharm-virtenv\DjangoPostgres\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\pycharm-virtenv\DjangoPostgres\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\pycharm-virtenv\DjangoPostgres\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\pycharm-virtenv\DjangoPostgres\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  177.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\pycharm-virtenv\DjangoPostgres\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\pycharm-virtenv\DjangoPostgres\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\pycharm-virtenv\DjangoPostgres\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\pycharm-virtenv\DjangoPostgres\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  72.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\pycharm-virtenv\DjangoPostgres\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\pycharm-virtenv\DjangoPostgres\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\pycharm-virtenv\DjangoPostgres\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  1040.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)

File "C:\pycharm-virtenv\DjangoPostgres\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  730.                     arg_vals.append(arg.resolve(context))

File "C:\pycharm-virtenv\DjangoPostgres\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  849.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)

File "C:\pycharm-virtenv\DjangoPostgres\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  903.                                                        (bit, current))  # missing attribute

Exception Type: VariableDoesNotExist at /reports/goals/
Exception Value: Failed lookup for key [get_div_goalsint_wdays] in 'None'
```

I tried this filter:

```
<tr>
   <td>Interest</td>
   <td class="data">${{int_numbers.get_sum_int_daily_numbers  | intcomma }}</td>
   <td class="data">${{int_goals.get_div_goalsint_wdays | intcomma }}</td>                  
    <td class="data"><font class="red">
        {% if int_numbers.get_sum_int_daily_numbers|sub:int_goals.get_div_goalsint_wdays is "None" %}
        0
        {% else %}
        ${{ int_numbers.get_sum_int_daily_numbers|sub:int_goals.get_div_goalsint_wdays | intcomma }}
         {% endif %}
                    </font>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Received the same error.

Is there a way with template tags and filters to correct this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that "int_goals" is undefined, thus None. If you try to do a math operation on 
`int_numbers.get_sum_int_daily_numbers - None.get_div_goalsint_wdays` python will throw an exception

Comment: The {% if int_goals %}{{ var|sub:}}{% endif %} worked!